# Find duplicates based on grandparent-instance id and filter out older duplicates based on timestamp field

Tags: python, django, duplicates, django-queryset

I’m trying to find duplicates of a Django model-object's instance based on grandparent-instance id and filter out older duplicates based on timestamp field.

I suppose I could do this with `distinct(*specify_fields)` function, but I don’t use Postgresql database ([docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/ref/models/querysets/#distinct)). I managed to achieve this with the following code:

```
queryset = MyModel.objects.filter(some_filtering…) \
    .only('parent_id__grandparent_id', 'timestamp' 'regular_fields'...) \
    .values('parent_id__grandparent_id', 'timestamp' 'regular_fields'...)

# compare_all_combinations_and_remove_duplicates_with_older_timestamps
list_of_dicts = list(queryset)
for a, b in itertools.combinations(list_of_dicts, 2):
    if a['parent_id__grandparent_id']: == b['parent_id__grandparent_id']:
        if a['timestamp'] > b['timestamp']:
            list_of_dicts.remove(b)
        else:
            list_of_dicts.remove(a)
```

However, this feels hacky and I guess this is not an optimal solution. Is there a better way (by better I mean more optimal, i.e. minimizing the number of times querysets are evaluated etc.)? Can I do the same with queryset’s methods?

My models look something like this:

```
class MyModel(models.Model):
    parent_id = models.ForeignKey('Parent'…
    timestamp = …
    regular_fields = …

class Parent(models.Model):
    grandparent_id = models.ForeignKey('Grandparent'…

class Grandparent(models.Model):
    …
```

Comment: Do the regular fields need to be equivalent? Do you want to *delete* these from the database, or only obtain the smallest *grand children* per grand parent so to speak? What if there are two grand children with the same timestamp? What database do you use?

Comment: 1) The regular fileds can be both unique or same as in other instances. 2) Just trying to filter, not delete. 3) Good question, I will have to think about that but I don't think that is a probable scenario. 4) Database is not decided, for now I'm using sqlite3, but on further stages of development I'll probably switch to MySql or Postgresql.

Comment: @Willem - I checked - case in which there are two grandchildren with the same timestamp is nearly impossible, but only after filtering the queryset (in the code above I tried to point at this at line 'MyModel.objects.filter(some_filtering…)' ).